# SUM() function + derived table + nested all in one

Tags: mysql, select, count, derived-table

Could someone please give me a hand in explaining in this example where the SUM function would go? The `count` I a referring to is NOT the function but rather the name of a column on my table. I am trying to get a literal count on the number of returned columns

```
SELECT count, post_id
     , DeliveryDate
     , DeliveryType
  FROM ( SELECT count, post_id
              , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_1' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) as DeliveryDate
              , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_2' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) as DeliveryType
           FROM wp_postmeta
         GROUP 
             BY post_id 
       ) AS derived_table
       
 WHERE DeliveryDate >= CURRENT_DATE
   AND DeliveryType = 'delivery'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that you want something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    post_id,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_1' THEN meta_value END) AS DeliveryDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'value_2' THEN meta_value END) AS DeliveryType
FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY
    post_id
HAVING
    DeliveryDate >= CURRENT_DATE AND
    DeliveryType = 'delivery';
```

Instead of subquerying and then checking the delivery date and type in an outer `WHERE` clause, we can instead just do a single aggregation and assert your requirements in the `HAVING` clause, usign the aliases defined earlier.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately that doesn't work though. I am not sure why but its related to the having clause. I fI remove it then it works but oviously returns every result and doesnt count anything.